# Grails REST API hide "class" in respond list

Tags: rest, grails

I'm using Grails 2.3.2 working on a REST API using the built in Grails REST support.  I'm having trouble getting rid of the "class" element in the JSON response.  Based on a tutorial by Bobby Warner, I have found adding the following to the resources.groovy file:

```
meterRenderer(JsonRenderer, Meter) {
    excludes = ['class']
}
```

This works fine for `show`, but for the `index` controller function, I'm `respond`ing with a list of `Meter`s.  In this, the "class" doesn't go away.  What does it take to get rid of this in the list response?

Edit: To clarify, I am looking for a way to leverage the Content Negotiation feature of Grails new `respond` functionality without locking myself down to `render as JSON` implementions.

Comment: Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495633/grails-grails-converters-json-removing-the-class-name

Comment: Thanks, nickdos.  I am new to Grails REST, so please take a look at my clarification edit and tell me if it makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

nickdos' [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12559158/1003697) had the answer.  I added the following to my BootStrap.groovy:

```
grails.converters.JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Meter) {
    return it.properties.findAll {k,v -> k != 'class'}
}
```

And the `respond` call results in no `"class"` item.  Oddly enough, I lost the `"id"` item in the process, but I'll save that for another SO question. :)

Comment: This does in fact remove the class `class` item, but removes the `id` param like you mentioned. Any work around for this?

Answer (score 1):

I guess if you switch to using [GSON](http://grails.org/plugin/gson) ([github](https://github.com/robfletcher/grails-gson)) instead of JSON then you need not worry about that particular exclusion.

That is driven by a [config setting](https://github.com/robfletcher/grails-gson#configuration) provided by the plugin as `grails.converters.gson.domain.include.class` (default is false).

Comment: Thanks, dmahapatro.  The GSON plugin looks awesome, but it seems that its RESTful controller support as it stands simply overwrites the existing controller scaffold with hard coded `render as GSON` responses rather than updating `respond` functionality.  I have edited my answer to hopefully clarify what I'm looking for.