# Grails JSON Converters and transient properties

Tags: grails, groovy

Using Grail 1.3.7 I found that the JSON converter ignores transient properties of Domain objects. 
Question: Is there an elegant way to work around this obstacle.

Bonus question: what's the reasoning behind excluding calculated fields(transient props) from being sent to the response????

Answer (score 5, accepted):

one way would be to manually create your json response, e.g.

```
["prop1" : obj.prop1, "prop2" : obj.prop2, ...] as JSON
```

Comment: you can fetch all properties by calling domainClass.properties and then interate over those properties and generate you json response. there are many property access methods. have a look at: http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/org/codehaus/groovy/grails/commons/DefaultGrailsDomainClass.html

Comment: I tried that, but I am not seeing a way to restrict to the subset of properties to the once I care about ... I must be overlooking something. But I agree with you, this is probably the best way to customize JSON response without creating a custom marshaller.

Answer (score 9):

what works for me is this one line

```
def jsonobj=domobj.properties as JSON
```

Comment: nice, I should try this next time.

Answer (score 5):

Transient is made exactly for that: [Variables may be marked transient to indicate that they are not part of the persistent state of an object](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.3.1.3)

And JSON is an serialized (=persistent) state of object

So, if you need it to be serialized - you have to create an new class, just for json serialization, that will have all fields you need to serialize.

Comment: +1 for correctly answering the bonus Q. However I feel there is a legitimate use case for marking a field transient but also getting the JSON converter to pick it up - a config flag would work miracles here :)

Answer (score 0):

If you need fine-grained control over the fields that are included/excluded in the JSON, I fine using the JSONBuilder a better option than the converter. Here's [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538423/grails-jsonbuilder/5543915#5543915) of how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the "marshallers" plug-in and define you transient property as virtual like this:

```
    static marshalling = {
      virtual {
        yourPropery { value, json -> json.value(value.yourPropery) }
      }
    }
```