# Grails render lists

Tags: xml, json, grails

I have a list like this:

```
 def bookList = Book.list()
```

and want to render it as XML/JSON, preferably using this approach:

```
render Book.list() as XML
```

However, I only want to render specific fields of that list, let's say: `field1`, `field2`, `field3`. The other useless stuff won't be shown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your case is simple enough, you could just collect what you need, e.g.:

```
def output = Book.list().collect { [
    field1: it.field1,
    field2: it.field2,
    field3: it.field3
] }

render output as XML
```

Using a builder (from Don's answer) is an excellent solution as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you want close control over the XML output you should use Grails' XMLBUilder instead of `as XML`. Here's [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5543915/2648) that shows how to render an object using JSONBuilder, excluding properties such as `class`, `metaClass`, etc.

To only modification this example needs to generate XML instead of JSON is to instantiate a `XMLBuilder` instead of a `JSONBuilder`.