# Full JSON render of object with nested object

Tags: json, mongodb, grails

I have a grails application with mongodb plugin.

All my domain objects are:

```
class Person {
  ObjectId id
  String name
}
```

and

```
class Like {
  ObjectId id
  Person from
  Person to
  Date createdAt
}
```

My controller should give a full data according to some `Like` by id:

```
class MyController {
  def like() {
    def like = Like.findById(new ObjectId("someIdHere"));
    render(like as grails.converters.JSON)
  }
}
```

I wish to receive a full JSON-object of like:

```
{
  "class":"Like",
  "id":{
    "class":"org.bson.types.ObjectId",
    "inc":1483542456,
    "machine":805594765,
    "new":false,
    "time":1340363115000,
    "timeSecond":1340363115
  },
  "createdAt":"2012-06-22T11:05:15Z",
  "from":{
    "class":"Person",
    "id":{ ... },
    "name":"Some name here"
  },
  "to":{
    "class":"Person",
    "id":{ ... },
    "name":"Some name here"
  }
}
```

but I've receive first-level properties of object:

```
{
  "class":"Like",
  "id":{
    "class":"org.bson.types.ObjectId",
    "inc":1483542456,
    "machine":805594765,
    "new":false,
    "time":1340363115000,
    "timeSecond":1340363115
  },
  "createdAt":"2012-06-22T11:05:15Z",
  "from":{
    "class":"Person",
    "id":"4fd31d453004dc0f010aca51"
  },
  "to":{
    "class":"Person",
    "id":"4fd31d463004dc0f010aca89"
  }
}
```

My question is: is there any way to construct full (with referenced objects) JSON of mongo db (DBObject) data object? I've found out this [solution with JSONBuiled](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5543915) with escaped fields 'class', metaClass' and 'dbo'. But I think it can be done with Expando classes but I cann't find the right way...

Thanks any way,
Maksim

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
render(like as grails.converters.JSON)
```

to

```
render(like as grails.converters.deep.JSON)
```

Comment: I've tried this way, but the response is

    {
      "class":"Like",
      "id":{...},
      "createdAt":"2012-06-22T11:05:15Z",
      "from": {
        "class":"Person",
        "id":{...},
        "name":null
      },
      "to":{
        "class":"Person",
        "id":{...},
        "name":null
      }
    }

So the deep configuration doesn't trigger the lazy methods.

Comment: deep.JSON is now deprecated. Use the JSON.use("deep") for deep conversions.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the standard way is to use named configs now so you want

```
JSON.use("deep") {
    render like as JSON
}
```

Comment: I've tried this way, but the response is

`    {
      "class":"Like",
      "id":{...},
      "createdAt":"2012-06-22T11:05:15Z",
      "from": {
        "class":"Person",
        "id":{...},
        "name":null
      },
      "to":{
        "class":"Person",
        "id":{...},
        "name":null
      }
    }`

So the deep configuration doesn't trigger the lazy methods.

Answer (score 1):

If this continues to be a problem for you, you might want to try another JSON library, like [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/), which gives much more control over serialising objects to JSON than the Grails JSON libraries do.

Comment: Hi! I've wrote a custom work around my classe. I know it is not good for me). Next time I'll use your advice, I think.
Any way thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Set the Child association to non lazy.
So

```
   class Like {
  ObjectId id
  Person from
  Person to
  Date createdAt



 static mapping = {
        from lazy: false
    }

}
```

Comment: unlazy configuration wasn't suit me well... But can help.
Thnx!

Comment: NEVER do that, imagine that you have many nested objects and you just want to change one attribute, with lazy false you'll load in memory all the objects, the nested objects, the sub-nested objects in the nested objects, etc.