# Groovy JSONBuilder issues

Tags: json, groovy

I'm trying to use JsonBuilder with Groovy to dynamically generate JSON.  I want to create a JSON block like:

```
{
    "type": {
        "__type": "urn",
        "value": "myCustomValue1"
    },
    "urn": {
        "__type": "urn",
        "value": "myCustomValue2"
    },
    "date": {
        "epoch": 1265662800000,
        "str": "2010-02-08T21:00:00Z"
    },
    "metadata": [{
        "ratings": [{
            "rating": "NR",
            "scheme": "eirin",
            "_type": {
                "__type": "urn",
                "value": "myCustomValue3"
            }
        }],
        "creators": [Jim, Bob, Joe]
    }]
}
```

I've written:

```
def addUrn(parent, type, urnVal) {
    parent."$type" {
        __type "urn"
        "value" urnVal
    }
}

String getEpisode(String myCustomVal1, String myCustomVal2, String myCustomVal3) {
    def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
    def root = builder {
        addUrn(builder, "type", myCustomVal1)
        addUrn(builder, "urn", "some:urn:$myCustomVal2")
        "date" {
            epoch 1265662800000
            str "2010-02-08T21:00:00Z"
        }
       "metadata" ({
                ratings ({
                        rating "G"
                        scheme "eirin"
                        addUrn(builder, "_type", "$myCustomVal3")
                })
                creators "Jim", "Bob", "Joe"                    
        })
    }

    return root.toString();
}
```

But I've run into the following issues:

1. Whenever I call `addUrn`, nothing is returned in the string.  **Am I misunderstanding how to use methods in Groovy?**
2. None of the values are encapsulated in double (or single) quotes in the returned string.
3. Anytime I use a `{`, I get a '_getEpisode_closure2_closure2@(insert hex)' in the returned value.

Is there something wrong with my syntax?  Or can someone point me to some example/tutorial that uses methods and/or examples beyond simple values (e.g. nested values within arrays).

*NOTE: This is a watered down example, but I tried to maintain the complexity around the areas that were giving me issues.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have to use `delegate` in `addUrn` method instead of
   passing the `builder` on which you are working.
2. It is because you are doing a `toSting()` or `toPrettyString()` on `root` instead of `builder`.
3. Solved if #2 is followed.

**Sample:**

```
def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
def root = builder {
              name "Devin"
              data {
                 type "Test"
                 note "Dummy"
              }
              addUrn(delegate, "gender", "male")
              addUrn(delegate, "zip", "43230")
           }


def addUrn(parent, type, urnVal) {
    parent."$type" {
        __type "urn"
        "value" urnVal
    }
}

println builder.toPrettyString()
```

**Output:-**

```
{
    "name": "Devin",
    "data": {
        "type": "Test",
        "note": "Dummy"
    },
    "gender": {
        "__type": "urn",
        "value": "male"
    },
    "zip": {
        "__type": "urn",
        "value": "43230"
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup, the `delegate` did the trick.  However, when I do builder.toString() I get a stackOverflowError (ReflectiveOperationException).

Comment: @Devin What script are you trying with? Are you getting exception from my sample code?

Comment: @Devin Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538423/grails-jsonbuilder) if you are talking about nested objects.

Comment: By commenting out my nested types (in this case, the 'metadata'), it worked wonderfully.  I'll take a look at that link and see what I can learn.  Thanks!

Comment: @Devin Just comment out `addUrn` inside `metadata` everything will work fine. Three things to take care: 1.`delegate` has to be set to the immediate parent. In this case, `delagate` has to be `ratings` when you call addUrn inside ratings. 2. You would not get a json array for `metadata` and `ratings` with the implementation you have now, it will be normal json object. Have to use `.collect` hopefully to get a list to be converted to json array. 3. Finally, have a look at [StreamingJsonBuilder](http://groovy.codehaus.org/gapi/groovy/json/StreamingJsonBuilder.html) to use instead of JsonBuilder.

Comment: How do you set the value of `delegate` to the immediate parent?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32527/discussion-between-devin-and-dmahapatro)