# Groovy JsonBuilder call methods to add information

Tags: groovy, jsonbuilder

The following code works fine

```
def json = new JsonBuilder()

json {
  writeNumbers(delegate, "myNumbers")
}

println json.toPrettyString()

def writeNumbers(json, name) {
  json."$name" {
      "w" 32
      "h" 32
  }
}
```

But as soon as I move or add a writeNumbers call inside of another 'scope', I get a stackoverflow exception; just like so

```
def json = new JsonBuilder()

json {
  scopes {
    writeNumbers(delegate, "myNumbers")
  }
}

println json.toPrettyString()

def writeNumbers(json, name) {
  json."$name" {
      "w" 32
      "h" 32
  }
}
```

Result:

```
Caught: java.lang.StackOverflowError
java.lang.StackOverflowError
```

Why is this happening and how can I get around it?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is caused by the underlying error that the method `writeNumbers` is unknown when building the chain of closures.

You need to change:

```
writeNumbers(delegate, "myNumbers")
```

to

```
this.writeNumbers(delegate, "myNumbers")
```

And it will work...  Interesting though, this *feels* like a bug... I'll investigate if I get some free time ;-)

#### Edit:  Found [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17355304/setting-delegate-value-with-groovy-jsonbuilder) which shows the same thing