# POGO to Mongo DBObject

Tags: mongodb, grails

Sorry this is a newbie question for Grails and Mongo, as I'm getting myself confused.

I have a POGO (non Domain class) with nested structures, that I need to store in MongoDB. I have example code as below, but this will only produce a map of properties of the top level object, and the insert fails because of the nested Name object

```
class Name {
    String firstName
    String lastName
}

class Details {
    Name name
    String street
    String city
    String postcode

    Name[] siblings
}

// Get only the properties we want to save 
def dbObject = details.properties.findAll { !['class', 'metaClass'].contains(it.key) }

// Insert it into the details collection
db.details.insert(dbObject)
```

I have then tried this example code answer [Grails JSONBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5538423/grails-jsonbuilder/5543915#5543915) but I get the following stack trace

```
org.apache.commons.lang.UnhandledException: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.exceptions.ConverterException: Unconvertable Object of class: java.util.LinkedHashMap
        at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.converters.AbstractConverter.toString(AbstractConverter.java:112)
        at grails.converters.JSON.toString(JSON.java:232)
        at grails.converters.JSON$toString.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at JSONSerializer.getJSON(JsonSerializer.groovy:21)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could register custom JSON marshaller for your classes in BootStrap.groovy.

```
def init = { servletContext ->

    def NameMarshaller = { Name it ->
        [firstName:it.firstName, lastName:it.lastName]
    }

    def DetailsMarshaller = { Details it->
        [name:it.name,...,siblings:it.siblings]
    }


    JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Name, NameMarshaller)
    JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Details, DetailsMarshaller)
    ...
}
```

In you app, just do

```
db.details.insert(detailsObject as JSON)
```

Properties in parent and children class registered in marshallers will be persisted, 'class' and 'metaClass' will not be since  you do not list them, you could save the line of properties filtering in your code. Custom marshaller simply converts your POGO to a map.

Comment: Good idea Jiwei. Have any idea how to invoke grails monodb plugin's default marshaller?